# How do I move the title pictures above title, author & name?

Tags: graphics, positioning, includegraphics

This will be trivial for frequent users. But, how do I move my title pictures above author, title and name?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[cc]{titlepic}

\titlepic{\includegraphics  [width=4cm]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics [width=4cm]{example-image-b}}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Internship Report}
\author{FirstName LastName}
\date{November 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below will point you in the right direction

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\title{
\leavevmode\smash{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo}}\\
The Title
}
\author{%
  The Author
}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Does this suit your requirements?

If you feel the answer is as per your requirements please upvote the answer by clicking on the red triangle at the left and the tick mark below it

Comment: Yes, that was great. Thank you !

Comment: If the question can be closed please accept the answer by ticking on the check mark